# Install opam in Mac OS

Tags: macos, ocaml, opam

I want to install `opam` in Mac OS X EL Capitan 10.11.1, but I got the following error:

```
Pro:~ $ brew install opam
Error: You must `brew link ocaml' before opam can be installed
Pro:~ $ brew link ocaml
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/ocaml/4.02.3... 
Error: Could not symlink lib/ocaml/Makefile.config
/usr/local/lib/ocaml is not writable.
```

Could anyone help?

PS: I think my OCaml installation is totally a mess under my Mac OS. How can I remove OCaml completely before doing anything?

**Edit 1:**

So with the help of John and Daniel, I first solved the permission problem, then `brew update`, then `brew remove ocaml`, then `brew install opam`.

Comment: How did you install OCaml in the first place?

Comment: I installed OCaml long time ago, and it was 4.01. Today I wanted to install `menhir` via `brew`, it installed OCaml 4.02 automatically for me, and then got an error of installation. Then I thought I needed to install opam for a better package management, then I had to delete manually several files for that, eg., /usr/local/lib/ocaml...

Comment: For those who downvoted this question... is it because it is too easy?

Comment: But what method did you use to install OCaml?  I'm asking because that might tell me how you should uninstall it.

Comment: I installed OCaml long long time ago in Mac, and I did not remember how. Today I decided to start code OCaml in Mac (I have been always coding OCaml in ubuntu).

Comment: Well, you can check if you installed it using `brew` by typing `brew list` and seeing if OCaml shows in the list.  If so, you could `brew uninstall ocaml`.

Comment: Indeed, i just "brew uninstall ocaml" 4.02.3, which was installed automatically when I installed `menhir`. But I am not sure if there is still anything left of OCaml 4.01 I installed long time ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104210/discussion-between-john-messenger-and-softtimur).

Comment: FYI I use OCaml over MacPorts since 5-6 years now, never had such issues, and it is ridiculously easy to write your own ports with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message it seems that you have a permission problem in your brew install. You should do something like:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```